# How to check if an Multidimensional Array has an element at the specified index?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexing

I want to know what is the value of the 2nd index of my array.

I have something like this:

```
$a[][1]= 10;
$a[][0]= 20;
$a[][1]= 12;
$a[][0]= 25;
```

I want to get only the values from $a wich 2nd index is 1.

**I need to do a comparison and if the answer is correct, get the value**

From this example, elements will be:

```
$a[0][1]
$a[2][1]
```

I know about [array_key_exists](https://www.php.net/array_key_exists) but i dont know how to use it with Multidimensional arrays.

Any help?

Thanks.

**Solution I was looking for.**

```
$a = array();

$a[][1] = b1;
$a[][0] = b2;
$a[][0] = c1;
$a[][1] = c2;

foreach ($a AS $key => $aVal ) 
  if (array_key_exists(1,$aVal)) 
    echo $a[$key][1] . "<br>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried **isset($a[$specified_index])**?

Here is some code:

```
foreach ( $a AS $key => $aVal ) {
    if ( array_key_exists(1,$aVal) ) {
        var_dump($key,$aVal);
    }
}
```

Comment: Results are Ok. Edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($a as $key => $value)
{
    if(isset($value[1]))
    {
        if($value[1] == 1)
        {
           echo "value is 1";
        }
        else
        {
           echo "value is not 1 but is ".$value[1];
        }
    }
}
```

thx to @Havelock

Comment: Im not sure if it is what i am looking for. I have a 2 columns array. Or i am confused.

Comment: @Baumannzone, `$value` is the array from the second dimension. The problem with the above code snippet is, that you don't always set the index `1`...

Comment: It dont work for me. I think you didnt get my problem.
However, i think @blue got this.

Comment: Well, now I believe there are 2 posibles solutions. It's Ok now.